# mysql php COUNT by same value in column GROUP BY to echo out

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by

I'm trying to figure out a solution to a query.

### **Question :**

I need to find the **sum of rows** which have the same value in a certain column. From this I then need to echo out certain bits of information along with the total count each value is seen (i.e. if 'project_id' has two rows with the same value as 11122 then the total count will be 2). I don't know the values I will need as these will be random project numbers in my table.

The column name I need to count by is 'project_id'.

I can't figure out how to echo in the following way:

> Project ID = 11122  Total Reviews = 2
>
> Project ID = 99999 Total Reviews = 5

Thanks!

Comment: The `above` query? What query?

Comment: `SELECT project_id, COUNT(*) as TotalReviews FROM  YourTable GROUP BY project_id`?

Comment: @D4V1D Sorry wrote it in a rush (dissertation!)

Comment: @Sean - Works a treat, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above in the comments, Sean's answer works a treat!

> SELECT project_id, COUNT(*) as TotalReviews FROM YourTable GROUP BY project_id